# Convert cents value in this INTO WORDS conversion Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code which convert numerical value into words. I just want to add cents in words if user inputs an amount which have a cents in value.

ex. If I have an amount of 1,000.88. The value in words will be **ONE THOUSAND PESOS AND EIGHTY EIGHY CENTS ONLY**.

**UPDATE:**
Code was edited to split the whole value and cents value. The only thing remaining is the conversion of cents into words.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MhN2d/6/)

```
var NUMBER2TEXT = {
        ones: ['', 'ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE', 'SIX', 'SEVEN', 'EIGHT', 'NINE', 'TEN', 'ELEVEN', 'TWELVE', 'THIRTEEN', 'FOURTEEN', 'FIFTEEN', 'SIXTEEN', 'SEVENTEEN', 'EIGHTEEN', 'NINETEEN'],
        tens: ['', '', 'TWENTY', 'THIRTY', 'FOURTY', 'FIFTY', 'SIXTY', 'SEVENTY', 'EIGHTY', 'NINETY'],
        sep: ['', ' THOUSAND ', ' MILLION ', ' BILLION ', ' TRILLION ', ' QUADRILLION ', ' QUINTILLION ', ' SEXTILLION ']
        };

        (function( ones, tens, sep ) {

        var input = document.getElementById( 'totalamountpaid' ),
        output = document.getElementById('words');

        input.onkeyup = function() {
        var val = this.value,
        arr = [],
        str = '',
        i = 0;

        if ( val.length === 0 ) {
        output.textContent = 'No amount paid';
        return;  
        }

        val = val.replace(/,/g,'');
        if ( isNaN( val ) ) {
        output.textContent = 'Invalid input.';
        return;   
        }


       val = val.toString();
       var valArray = val.split('\.', 2); //splits val into two seperate integers, whole numbers and decimals, in an array.   
       val = valArray[0]; //this is the whole number
       var val2 = valArray[1]; //this should be the decimals

        if(val2 != null && val2 != ''){
        //convert the decimals here
        var str2 = 'AND TWENTY CENTS';
        }else{
        var str2 = '';
        }

        while ( val ) {
        arr.push( val % 1000 );
        val = parseInt( val / 1000, 10 );   
        }

        while ( arr.length ) {
        str = (function( a ) {
        var x = Math.floor( a / 100 ),
        y = Math.floor( a / 10 ) % 10,
        z = a % 10;

        return ( x > 0 ? ones[x] + ' HUNDRED ' : '' ) +                 
        ( y >= 2 ? tens[y] + ' ' + ones[z] : ones[10*y + z] ); 
        })( arr.shift() ) + sep[i++] + str;                     
        }



        output.textContent = str + ' ' + str2 + ' PESOS ONLY';       
        };

        })( NUMBER2TEXT.ones, NUMBER2TEXT.tens, NUMBER2TEXT.sep );
```

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is, you seem to have a good start on the idea. It's not going to be a simple, because language isn't as logical as numbers.

Comment: I don't know the condition I will add after the whole number and how to combine it.

Comment: For me, the simplest way to do it would be to `mystr.split(".");` and deal with them as two separate variables. The .split function will put them into in array, do you understand arrays?

Comment: Yeah, but if you don't mind much easier if you edit the fiddle for me to see how is it works?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how your program works, but I can try.

Comment: Please check the fiddle. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the wait, for some reason this line was attacking my code.

```
val = parseInt( val.replace(/,/g,''), 10 );
```

I changed it to:

```
val = val.replace(/,/g,'');
```

which seems to have the same functionality while allowing me to do my thing. Here is the code. I use regexes to test for a period in `val` (the if statement), and then to split val into things before and after a period. The `2` in the split function should only allow for 2 strings to come out of it, meaning 10.20 would become '10' and '20' where 1.2.3 would become '1' and '2', and throw away 3. Arrays start at 0, so `valArray[0]` is the first string in the array, and `valArray[1]` is the second one.

```
val = val.toString();
var valArray = val.split('\.', 2); //splits val into two seperate integers, whole numbers and decimals, in an array.   
val = valArray[0]; //this is the whole number
var val2 = valArray[1]; //this should be the decimals

if(val2 != null && val2 != ''){
//convert the decimals here
var str2 = 'TWENTY CENTS';
}
else{
var str2 = '';
}
```

UPDATE: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MhN2d/3/)

Comment: Can I view the result in fiddle?

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't include the link! Check the Update!

Comment: You can `.split()` without checking for the character. If there's no period, you will receive an array of length 1. You should probably make a single function to handle the number-to-word conversion, then pass both parts of the array to that function separately to get your final answer (e.g., `var amount = numberToWords(part[0]) + ' dollars and ' + numberToWords(part[1]) + ' cents'`)

Comment: It's up to you to convert it to words, I was just showing how to split at the period. TWENTY CENTS is just an example.

Comment: Answer updated slightly as per user113215, though you should take his notes on your overall design as well.

Comment: Just need the conversion of cents.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete version using dollars and cents

```js
const num2text = {
  ones: ['', 'ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE', 'SIX', 'SEVEN', 'EIGHT', 'NINE', 'TEN', 'ELEVEN', 'TWELVE', 'THIRTEEN', 'FOURTEEN', 'FIFTEEN', 'SIXTEEN', 'SEVENTEEN', 'EIGHTEEN', 'NINETEEN'],
  tens: ['', '', 'TWENTY', 'THIRTY', 'FOURTH', 'FIFTY', 'SIXTY', 'SEVENTY', 'EIGHTY', 'NINETY'],
  sep: ['', ' THOUSAND ', ' MILLION ', ' BILLION ', ' TRILLION ', ' QUADRILLION ', ' QUINTILLION ', ' SEXTILLION ']
};
const convert = function(val) {
  if (val.length === 0) {
    return '';
  }

  val = val.replace(/,/g, '');
  if (isNaN(val)) {
    return 'Invalid input.';
  }


  let [val1, val2] = val.split(".")
  let str2 = "";
  if (val2 != null && val2 != '') {
    //convert the decimals here
    var digits = (val2+"0").slice(0,2).split("");
    str2 = num2text.tens[+digits[0]] + " " + num2text.ones[+digits[1]]
  }
  let arr = [];
  while (val1) {
    arr.push(val1 % 1000);
    val1 = parseInt(val1 / 1000, 10);
  }
  let i = 0;
  let str = "";
  while (arr.length) {
    str = (function(a) {
      var x = Math.floor(a / 100),
        y = Math.floor(a / 10) % 10,
        z = a % 10;

      return (x > 0 ? num2text.ones[x] + ' HUNDRED ' : '') +
        (y >= 2 ? num2text.tens[y] + ' ' + num2text.ones[z] : num2text.ones[10 * y + z]);
    })(arr.shift()) + num2text.sep[i++] + str;
  }

  return str +
    ' DOLLARS ' +
    (str2 ? ' AND ' + str2 + ' CENTS' : '') +
    ' ONLY';
};


window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("totalamountpaid").addEventListener("input", function() {
    document.getElementById("words").innerHTML = convert(this.value)
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="totalamountpaid" placeholder="input amount" />
<br><br>
<label id="words"><label>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an improvement on @mplungjan

```
const num2text = {
ones: [
    '',
    'ONE',
    'TWO',
    'THREE',
    'FOUR',
    'FIVE',
    'SIX',
    'SEVEN',
    'EIGHT',
    'NINE',
    'TEN',
    'ELEVEN',
    'TWELVE',
    'THIRTEEN',
    'FOURTEEN',
    'FIFTEEN',
    'SIXTEEN',
    'SEVENTEEN',
    'EIGHTEEN',
    'NINETEEN',
],
tens: [
    '',
    '',
    'TWENTY',
    'THIRTY',
    'FOURTY',
    'FIFTY',
    'SIXTY',
    'SEVENTY',
    'EIGHTY',
    'NINETY',
],
sep: [
    '',
    ' THOUSAND ',
    ' MILLION ',
    ' BILLION ',
    ' TRILLION ',
    ' QUADRILLION ',
    ' QUINTILLION ',
    ' SEXTILLION ',
],
};

export const convertAmountToWords = function (
amount: any,
currency?: string,
smallestUnit?: string
) {
if (!amount) return '';

if (amount.length === 0) {
    return '';
}

amount = amount.replace(/,/g, '');

if (isNaN(amount)) {
    return 'Invalid input.';
}

// eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
let [val1, val2] = amount.split('.');
let str2 = '';
if (val2 != null && val2 != '') {
    //convert the decimals here
    const digits = (val2 + '0').slice(0, 2).split('');
    str2 = convertAmountToWords(digits.join(''));
}
const arr = [];
while (val1) {
    arr.push(val1 % 1000);
    val1 = parseInt(String(val1 / 1000), 10);
}
let i = 0;
let str = '';
while (arr.length) {
    str =
        (function (a) {
            if (!a) return '';

            const x = Math.floor(a / 100),
                y = Math.floor(a / 10) % 10,
                z = a % 10;

            return (
                (x > 0 ? num2text.ones[x] + ' HUNDRED AND ' : '') +
                (y >= 2
                    ? num2text.tens[y] + ' ' + num2text.ones[z]
                    : num2text.ones[10 * y + z])
            );
        })(arr.shift()) +
        num2text.sep[i++] +
        str;
}

if (!currency) return str;

return (
    str +
    ` ${currency}` +
    (str2 ? ', ' + str2 + ` ${smallestUnit}` : '')
).toLowerCase();
};
```

Comment: How does this improve the other answer? Some explanation of the changes you've 
 made would be useful.