# How to restore a database from .ibd,.frm files

Tags: database, xampp, frm

I have .opt, .ibd and .frm files. I was not able to restore it.

My xampp is not working. Facing some port issue.

So i copy and pasted the .ibd,.frm files to another xampp which is working but I received " #1932- Table doesnt exist in engine".

I want my stored procedures and tables in the specific database.

Comment: If you still need a currency formatter, I fixed this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60771383/295783

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for days for a solution to Table 'table_name' doesn't exist in engine to no avail. I was able to restore my data as follows

Background : Running a web application on a raspberry PI, raspberry PI crashed, no backup of course, I rebuilt the OS but the mariadb service wouldnt restart

This method is not for the faint hearted and requires a good knowledge of SQL

1. Create a Test Database (IE DB name Test)

2  Hex dump respective table's .frm file in original directory to identify the table column names

3  build SQL (text file) to create new table, note best guess with datatypes

4  Create new table in Database Test

5  Discard TableSpace

6  Copy in .ibd file (to Test database directory)

7  Import tablespace

8  Stop and restart the mysql service

9  If service doesnt restart, check err log, edit my file recovery status to say 3 from 0

10  Do SQL query to check data, unlikely to be 100% correct

11  If not 100% correct but readable, copy original .frm file over Test .frm file

12 Stop and restart mysql service

13 Use SQL Describe table_name to obtain original table structure

14 Delete Test database and recreate using steps 5-7

15 Select statement should now show good data

16 Create new production database

17 Create new_tablename select * from Test.new_tablename;

18 Repeat for all tables

Good luck